# How to read the CSV based on encoding in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, csv, character-encoding

I used https://github.com/roo-rb/roo to parse the CSV file in Ruby on Rails.
Code is following as

```
data = Roo::CSV.new(obj.public_url, csv_options: {encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1})
```

There is an issue when open the CSV file  encoded by UTF-8. (Unknown characters is shown.)

Is there any solution to read the CSV file of any encodings?

Or How can I get the encoding type of CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try without the `csv_options` parameter?

Or try the usual:

```
File.read('foo.csv').encoding => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're specifying the CSV to be encoded as ISO-8859-1 (`{encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1}`), and if you're trying to open the CSV as UTF-8 it will show weird symbols on those characters not accepted by ISO.

I suggest to try with another options to ask Roo to encode the file as UTF-8:

```
data = Roo::CSV.new(obj.public_url, csv_options: {encoding: Encoding::UTF_8})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your CSV file is get from an url. If this is the case then you need to use `open-uri` to stream the file and detect its encoding with the following code:

```
require 'uri'
en = open('obj.public_url').read.encoding => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Then, you can use `roo` to read your CSV file with the correct encoding.

```
data = Roo::CSV.new(obj.public_url, csv_options: {encoding: en})
```

Comment: open('obj.public_url').read.encoding always return <Encoding:ASCII-8BIT> for any encoding type.

Comment: Could you download the file first and detect its encoding?